# RPC implementation requiring very long polling / "Backwards RPC"

Tags: web-services, language-agnostic, rpc

I'm in the early stages of planning a project.  I want to know the conventional/easy way of doing this that does not involve implementing my own protocol.

I am aware of the concept of RPC - having a server that exposes certain procedures that can be invoked by a client.  Well, I have a lot of clients but unfortunately I can't directly connect to them (NAT/Firewall issues; they're mostly home PCs).  So, I was thinking of having the clients directly connect to the server and invoke a "Poll for operation" method.  I guess this is "backwards RPC."  That is, all that this method will do is block until the server decides something needs to be done (this could take seconds or days) and then return a fragment of data that indicates what needs to be done, and actually invoke the appropriate code on the client and return it to the server.  Note the 3 steps:

1. Client polls the server.  Wait a potentially long time.
2. Server returns some operation in serialized form.  e.g., "send me a file"
3. Client executes the operation and sends the server this

So I don't understand how I can really do this using something that goes over HTTP, because with HTTP there's just a request and response.  I guess I could do this using a GET (steps one and two) and a POST (step 3) but I'm hoping for something a little more elegant because that includes a lot of bookkeeping on the server side (a cookie per request or something, etc).

I'm looking for a cross platform way of doing this.  The client will be in C# but I haven't made up my mind about the server.  I don't care if this is done over HTTP or not so "web-services" may or may not be applicable.

Any ideas on a protocol/convention that fits my description?  Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to establish two way communication and you want to be able to navigate NATs/firewalls/etc., it sounds like you might be interested in [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).